# Launch 3rd party app and resume it on the state where the user has left it

Tags: android, android-intent

I am learning Android development, and discovered I can launch any third party app (Messenger, gallery, music player, etc) using Intents like this:

```
Intent intent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");
            startActivity(intent);
```

However, this always starts as a new app, even if my app is still running in the background. I want to launch messenger (or any other app) in such a way that it would be resumed in the state where the user has left it.

Comment: I'm not sure which, but perhaps there is a flag you can add to the Intent? There is a list of them in the documentation here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)

Comment: In my app I am using getLaunchForPackage()  to launch the app.According to docs this method will restart the app when I launch the app is there any replacement for getLaunchForPackage() to relaunch of app

Comment: @McAdam331 I have tried various flags but it didn't worked it always restarted the app from beginning instead of resuming where the user has left it..